# Get value from a bpy.types.Scene property

Tags: python

I have a few properties created like:

```
bpy.types.Scene.myprop = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Myprop",default=1)
```

I want to save their values to a text file but don't know how to extract the actual value (saving just myprop saves all object data instead of just the int value).
How to get the actual value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access using `bpy.context.scene` likes this: `print(bpy.context.scene.myprop)` or set it equal to a variable: `value = bpy.context.scene.myprop`, also in your post, make sure you have `IntProperty` not `InProperty` like you currently have.

Comment: Yep, using `bpy.context.scene` instead of `bpy.types.Scene` did the trick for me. Thx!